# How to add only 1 value when intersects?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, intersection

```
 if(CGRectIntersectsRect(m_Heart, m_sBirdSprite.boundingBox)){
            m_sHeart[i].visible=FALSE;
            m_fTime += 1;
        }
```

This is my code, and the problem is that i want to add only one value in m_fTime variable, but it is continuously adding +1 in m_fTime varible because it is in process to be intersecting, now is there any way to add only 1 value in it when it intersects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **BOOL** porperty

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(m_Heart, m_sBirdSprite.boundingBox) && [m_sHeart[i] isVisible]){
     m_sHeart[i].visible=FALSE;
     m_fTime += 1;
}
```

Comment: Clean solution using existing variables. (y)

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your kind answer @Himanshu Joshi its correct in terms of logic, but bit incorrect in terms of syntax i did try the same, i am not pointing your syntax wrong, just giving the correct syntax for our new/beginner friends. and i am marking your question as right answer.

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(m_sHearts, m_sBirdSprite.boundingBox) && m_sHeart[i].visible==TRUE){
        m_sHeart[i].visible=FALSE;
        m_fTime += 1;
    }
```

Comment: if condition executes only when the statement inside it is `true`. So,  there is no need to check the `TRUE` value for visibility in `m_sHeart[i].visible`

Comment: yes dude i marked your question as correct cause your logic was correct, and i used your syntax which shows me error, this is why wrote my answer with 100% correct and tested syntax. :P

Answer (score 1):

In expert programming a simple way to use Boolean flags.
Same here you can implement the Boolean flags in your problem,

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(m_Heart, m_sBirdSprite.boundingBox) && [m_sHeart[i] isVisible]){
     m_sHeart[i].visible=true;
     m_fTime += 1;
}
```

Comment: as you can see i have accepted the answer at top by himanshu, he sugessted the same, may be you didn't read it well...

Comment: sorry steve, i am new to it, and i don't have the idea exactly how you can mark the right answer, this is why i've written my answer, if you found it odd or in a sense of copy then i will delete it.

Comment: its ok, and welcome to stackoverflow, and keep this thing in mind that same answers will be reported to admin and he will block you if you will repeat this act again, but i am not reporting... :)

Comment: oh, i didn't know that, and honestly i didn't copy that, but by the way thanx man. vote up for you. :-)

Comment: don't do it like this man, you will be blocked, i think you didn't read the terms and conditions of stack overflow, there are certain boundaries and restriction over here, you can't do anything like this, please visit this url and read every topic or go through any question in your mind, 
http://stackoverflow.com/help/

Comment: oh, i will read it, and i will take care of this next time thank you very much.